# Rich links in WhatsApp with just 1 line description instead of 2?

Tags: html, meta-tags, whatsapp

I'm struggling with the rich links, while when I share a link from most of the websties I see two lines description.

For example Facebook:

```html
<meta name="description" content="This is a text description that is showing 2 description lines and a thumbnail without any problem or cut excepto for this.." />
```

My web site:

```html
<meta name="description" content="For some reason even if this text is shorter, I get a cut into the first line description">
```

Here I get a cut in the first line before the end of the sentence.

I'm getting a bit crazy here, it doesn't make apparently sense, it's me or WhatsApp trying to annoy me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with that line, but probably your title is 2 lines, and is taking deducing a line from the description as there's max 3 lines per rich link